# How to prevent PyDev's autopep8 import formatter from moving site.addsitedir() calls?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, pep8, autopep8

The Eclipse PyDev plugin includes fantastic integrated `autopep8` support. It formats the code to PEP8 style automatically on save, with several knobs and options to tailor it to your needs.

But the `autopep8` import formatter breaks `site.addsitedir()` usage.

```
import site

site.addsitedir('/opt/path/lib/python')

# 'ourlib' is a package in '/opt/path/lib/python', which 
# without the above addsitedir() would otherwise not import.
from ourlib import do_stuff
```

And after PyDev's `autopep8` import formatter, it changes it to:

```
import site

from ourlib import do_stuff

site.addsitedir('/opt/path/lib/python')
```

Which  breaks `from ourlib import do_stuff` with `ImportError: No module named ourlib`.

**Question:**

Is there a PyDev setting or `autopep8` command-line option to keep it from moving `site.addsitedir()` calls?

Comment: Just noting that the same issue happens for `sys.path.append('/opt/path/lib/python')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option I can find is to turn off import sorts in PyDev. This is not a complete solution, but it's better than completely turning off `autopep8` code formatting.

Just uncheck the `Sort imports on save?` option in the Eclipse/PyDev Preferences.

For Eclipse Kepler, Service Release 2, with PyDev 3.9.2, you can find it here:

```
Windows -> Preferences 
--> PyDev -> Editor -> Save Actions
----> "Sort imports on save?" (uncheck)
```

Answer (score 10):

Oldie but still relevant as I found this one issue.

I'm using VSCode and autopep8.
You can disable formatting by adding `# nopep8` to the relevant lines.

ps. Checked the docs for a link but could not find it :(

Comment: Any idea if this works on Eclipse PyDev? I haven't used it in quite a while.